# How to use a data type in a haskell package

Tags: haskell

I have three files. The first:

```
module AST where

data Prog a b = ...
```

The second

```
module ParseProg where

import qualified AST as A

progToAST :: String -> A.Prog String String
```

This is part of a package used for a homework assignment. I installed it with

```
$ cabal configure
$ cabal build 
$ cabal install
```

which seemed to work. My third program (testing) is

```
import ParseProg

val1 = progToAST "x"

-- prog :: A.Prog String String

fun1 :: Int -> Int
fun1 x = 2

-- val2 = fun1 val1
```

So the import works. If I uncomment prog though, I get

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘A.Prog’
```

Same thing if I try Prog or AST.Prog. Checking the type of val1 gets

```
> :type val1
> val1 :: CabParser-0.1.0.0:AST.Prog String String
```

And similarly uncommenting val2 gives

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
            with actual type ‘CabParser-0.1.0.0:AST.Prog String String’
```

Copying CabParser-0.1.... gives a parse error. How do I use the Prog data type in AST?

Comment: You don't have `import qualified AST as A` in your third program.

Comment: Now I get `"Could not find module ‘AST’
    it is a hidden module in the package ‘CabParser-0.1.0.0@CabPa_<nonsense>`

Comment: You'll have to list it in your `.cabal` file for `CabParser`. I don't remember the field name, but `ParseProg` will be listed in it already.

Comment: then do I do the configure, build, install again?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Great, this works. If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept. I can do it otherwise.

Comment: You go right ahead.

Answer (score 4):

Ryan solved this in the comments. I write the solution here.

The first issue is I did not import the AST in the third file, so it becomes:

```
import ParseProg
import AST as A
```

However, this gives an error

```
"Could not find module ‘AST’ it is a hidden module in the package ‘CabParser-0.1.0.0@CabPa_<nonsense>"
```

For some reason, AST is a hidden module in the package CabParser that I am using, so I have to make it an exposed module. In CabParser.cabal in the directory of the package, I add AST to the exposed modules:

```
exposed-modules:     ParseProg, AST
```

and remove it from the other-modules line. Then I build and install again with

```
$ cabal configure
$ cabal build 
$ cabal install
```

Then everything works.